# Rails show total column when data comes from model method

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a model Invoices

Table Invoices:
ID, PRODUCT, UNITS, PRICE

In my view, I want to show total for some columns.

For instance to show total quantity I can set in my controller:

```
@invoices = Invoice.group(:PRODUCT).select(ID, PRODUCT, UNITS, SUM(UNITS) AS TOTALUNITS, PRICE").order('PRODUCT ASC')

@units_total = @invoices.map(&:UNITS).sum
```

and in my view

```
<%= @units_total %>
```

and it returns the total in column UNITS. This works fine.

If I define in my model:

```
def total_amount
(self.PRICE * self.TOTALUNITS)
end
```

and then on the same way I want to show the total of total_amount, I tried in my controller:

```
@amount_total = @invoices.map(&:total_amount).sum
```

it doesn't work, as I assume that if I'm not using a column name the syntax must be different.

What should I enter then?

**UPDATE**
The problem comes form the fact that I'm using in model (self.PRICE * self.TOTALUNITS). I didn't include it when I posted the question as I thought it didn't matter. But if I replace(self.PRICE * self.TOTALUNITS) with (self.PRICE * self.UNITS) there's no error but values are obviously wrong.

Comment: what are the exact column names? show the corresponding part of  `schema.rb`

Comment: what you have taken is correct, check if you have the values in corresponding columns

Comment: That was just a simplified example.. But if in my view I use <%= invoice.total_amount %> it returns rows with correct values. But I do have null values in some row. So I'll try solution below.

Comment: I have updated the question. You were right the problem comes from the fact that I was actually using TOTALUNITS in method, not UNITS as I wrote firstly in the question. I thought it didn't matter but it does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have taken is correct, I think some of the invoices doesnot have the value, check using try,

```
def total_amount
  price = self.try(:PRICE) || 0
  units = self.try(:UNITS) || 0
  price * units
end
```

`make 0` if the corresponding field value is absent, so that you will not get an error.

Comment: I have updated the question, after fixing null values the problem is now undefined method `TOTALUNITS'. In my model I am actually multiplying PRICE * TOTALUNITS after selecting in controller SUM(UNITS) AS TOTALUNITS

Comment: but you do not have TOTALUNITS column in your table

Comment: No I don't. I just do select("SUM(UNITS) AS TOTALUNITS) in my controller (see updated question). And it works fine if I call in method total_amount. But as soon as I add @amount_total = @invoices.map(&:total_amount).sum and call it in view I get undefined method `TOTALUNITS'. MAybe because I'm applying sum to TOTALUNITS that is a sum already?

Comment: yes you cannot use `TOTALUNITS` in the model like that, since `self.TOTALUNITS` will search for a column `TOTALUNITS` in the table

Comment: Ok thanks. As this got messy already I will close it here. In case I can't find out the solution I'll create a new question specifically for this issue. Thanks again.

Comment: Ok sorry I overlooked it and it's supposed to achieve what I want. But I get  syntax error, unexpected tOP_ASGN, expecting keyword_end price = self.try(:PRICE) ||= 0 ^

Comment: This works fine to calculate the value in total column. But it doesn't show correct value for each row in table when I call <%= invoice.total_amount %>. And this happens because if I have 2 lines for same product, when it groups by product it does not sum UNITS. That's why I need PRICE * sum(UNITS) for each row, hence for each product. Your solutions still refers to my question before was edited. But in case I can create a separate method for values in table rows and keep yours for the total column.

Comment: you can change the name to something else, to get it worked,

Comment: I mean your method should be something like sum(price * units), not only price*units as you suggested. That  would give me the correct total for each product.

Comment: Otherwise to calculate value for each row I use the original one with TOTALUNITS, with of course a different name.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126525/discussion-between-sravan-and-catmal).

Answer (score 1):

You can check if this is working or not

```
@amount_total = @invoices.map{ |invoice| invoice.PRICE.to_f * invoice.UNITS.to_i }.sum
```

I don't know what error you are getting but it might be due to null values in the column.

Hope that helps!

Comment: I have updated the question, after fixing null values the problem is now undefined method `TOTALUNITS'. In my model I am actually multiplying PRICE * TOTALUNITS after selecting in controller SUM(UNITS) AS TOTALUNITS